# bxslider pager area showing when controls true and pager false

Tags: controls, bxslider, pager

I've tried the BXSlider and I'm quite fond of it. However, there is this one issue which probably is only with my website... When I use the following options, the pager "area" still shows but it is blank and it screws my layout since I have a border.

```
controls: true,
pager: false
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stiino0/9zeo56qt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just found it after a long search :)

I don't know the cause or why the area still showed, i'll let it know to the developer, perhaps it was the combo with my own css, dunno.

It was the following rule (which is default for showing the are, now I cannot enable it with a simple option). It was the 60px.

```
.bx-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto 60px;
}
```

Should I get a response from the developer, I'll post it here.

Cheers!